# Is there a way to get the plain html and css equivalent from a React Native app?

Tags: html, css, angularjs, react-native, ionic-framework

I have created an app with React Native and I want to get the html and css equivalent of the screens and components. The reason is that I already have an app made with Angular / ionic fully functional, and I'd like to get the styling and visual appearance of the RN app and apply it to the ionic app.
Is there some tools that can convert a React Native app into its static html and css equivalent ?

I rebuild the visual from scratch, but I have many screens and it is time intensive. I won't be able to finish on time.

Comment: You can try to inspect your application with debugging tools. Flipper was an option, there is the Chrome debugger or the internal "inspector" in the app, if you will open the debug menu. That's the closest thing you can get from RN, since the "final" output of RN suite is not HTML+CSS anymore.

Comment: No there is no tools to extract code from RN. But if you designed it in Figma, Figma has a plugin that lets you extract code from design docs. making your life quicker.

Comment: You might use react-native-web (https://necolas.github.io/react-native-web/) for some components.